# How to use events for controls that are dynamically created under an itemsControl?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a form in my project that has the controls created through use of a class.  There's an issue with this way of it though, since any of the controls I will create will be under an ItemsControl control, I'm not quite sure how I would access the events of any of the controls I create(textbox for example)

If I want to create a KeyPress event for my textbox, I have an error in the code:

```
Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types.
```

I'm only assuming this is because of my ItemsControl because I've ran into this same issue when trying to access controls' properties from within the ItemsControl and it was a nightmare to fix.  What's the real reason this is throwing an error?

Comment: `it was a nightmare to fix` - WPF is going to be a "nightmare" for you until you leave the winforms mentality behind and create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding. What event are you looking for and what do you expect to achieve by/after handling it?

Comment: Originally, I created my form by drag and dropping them onto my form from the toolbox until I read one of your posts that explained you can create them 'dynamically' and bind them to your form, which I then did to a very small form with only a few controls.  With this form I only have a label, textbox, and button and since there's no MaskedTextBox control in WPF I am working on creating logic for the textbox.  Originally, accessing the controls' properties was a headache(since under ItemsControl) I had to enumerate through every child control to get the property. I'll look into ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to put this functionality in the wrong place.

The code behind the `Window` that contains your `ItemsControl` is not the right place to put code which affects / is concerned about a particular UI element which is reused over and over in an `ItemsControl`. You need to isolate the "pieces" of your UI and create modular, individual units of functionality / Visuals that can be reused and work independently of their "surrounding" environment.

In this case, you have to replace the `TextBox` in your `DataTemplate` (in XAML) for another UI element which performs like a TextBox, but only allows numeric / masked input.

There are 3 different approaches to that:

**1** - replace the `TextBox` for a [`MaskedTextBox`](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox) from the WPF toolkit.

**2** - replace the `TextBox` for a [`UserControl`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32825/How-to-Creating-a-WPF-User-Control-using-it-in-a-W) that *contains* the `TextBox` and uses code behind to perform the numeric-only input functionality.

**3**- replace the `TextBox` for a [Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that *inherits* from `TextBox` and performs the input validation in on it's own.

The difference between approaches 2 and 3 is that a `UserControl` is a composite piece of UI made up of XAML + Code Behind, which can *contain* any other UI elements, whereas a `Custom Control` is a code-only (no XAML / *"Lookless"*) class that is *derived* from a Control (such as `TextBox`) which requires a [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to function properly.

Notice that neither of these approaches involve putting code behind the Window that contains your `itemsControl`. It is simply a matter of separation of concerns and proper encapsulation of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the event dynamically, using the `AddHandler` keyword:

```
Dim tb As New TextBox
...
AddHandler tb.TextChanged, AddressOf tb_TextChanged
```

where `tb_TextChanged` is the method that handles the event:

```
Private Sub tb_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TextChangedEventArgs)

    ...

End Sub
```

If you need to unsubscribe, use the `RemoveHandler` keyword.

Comment: How would one use eventArgs with this way?  What I'm looking to do is create a textbox that will only allow numeric digits but won't be able to do keyChar without an eventarg to pass to the function

Comment: @Criel, the EventArgs are passed by the control that raises the event. All you have to do is receive the EventArgs in the event handler.